# Sync Google Calendar in Lua

Tags: lua

Does anyone have an example how to sync data to Google Calendar via Lua?
Finally just changing a dates entry and reading its content.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not offer a client library for Lua so you will have to use their REST API. This means the best way to get started is by looking at the documentation at http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/getting_started.html.

Besides plain Lua you will need at least something like [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/) to retrieve and create data over the wire and based on a quick glance of their documentation some sort of authentication library is required as well (I found [LuaOAuth](https://github.com/ignacio/LuaOAuth) with a quick google, but I can not recommend it because I have personally not used it).